# Unity2D AudioSource on Collision

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, collision

I attached an audiosource to a gameobject and in a script attached to the played I put :

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {
         if (col.gameObject.tag == "tag") {
             col.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
             Destroy(col.gameObject);
             GetComponent<Score>().score += 1;
         }
     }
```

In order to play a sound when there is a collision. But it's not working and I wonder where is the mistake. Thanks for the help.
Everything but the sound is working it's not a collision nor a volume problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are destroying the GameObject that is playing the audio immediatly after you play it. Consider attaching the AudioSource to a other GameObject instead.

Comment: You are welcome! Consider marking this comment as an answer so everything is correct :)